# Very slow prestashop

Tags: php, apache, prestashop

sorry if my question isn't written the proper way.
Please let me know what i can do to help you help me :)

I'm working on a Prestashop website that suddently started to become very slow on everypages (front and back).

I noticed that it is the request that take long time to be processed.
Once the server start sending response, it is fast.

When i go to www.mywebsite.com **it is very slow** for processing request.
When i go to www.mywebsite.com/phpmyadmin **it is fast**

do you have any idea ??

prestashop 1.6.1.6

Linux my_host_name 3.10.23-xxxx-std-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 18 14:48:24 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: you have tried to view the site without modules or override? you can disable it from the page called "performance"

Comment: thanks a lot, but i'm working in production (I KNOW, I DONT HAVE CHOICE :( )
i can't disable anything, just do some ninja debugging

Comment: uses for instance if ($ _ SERVER ['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '<your ip>') in classes/hook.php for modules and classes/Tools.php for override

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem some time ago with a shop when I installed an script for detect country from IP address. This script was executed in every request so until script finish the rest of the page does not load. Anyway, you can active Debug Profiling to know witch part of your page is delaying the response.

Go to `/confif/defines.inc.php` and set `_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_` to `true`. Then reload your page and you will see at the bottom a detailed info about every loaded part of your entire shop page.

Good luck.